# How to show Treemap chart from Google chart using php?

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

I have problem when I want to show my treemap chart in browser. When I call my testingTreemap.php, my browser didn't show anything, just the tittle. I confuse how to set my data become values in treemap chart.

This is my testingTreemap.php

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['treemap']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart(){


        //var dataFromPHP = <?php echo file_get_contents('clientdata.json'); ?>;
        $dataFromPHP = file_get_contents('clientdata.json');
        $json = json_decode($dataFromPHP, TRUE);

        // console.log(dump_dataFromPHP);
        $provinsi = 'SELECT provinsi , LEFT(provinsi, '') AS lala FROM data_client';
        $query = 'SELECT provinsi ,kode_sales, gaji, count(kode_sales) AS T_nasabah FROM data_client GROUP BY kode_sales';
        //var newData = [];
        ['Location', 'Parent' , 'Size', 'Color'];

        $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $execProv = mysqli_query($con,$provinsi);
        echo "['".$row['lala']."'," null, 0, 0"],";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execProv)){ 
        echo "['".$row['provinsi']."','".$row['lala']."',"0,0"],";
        }
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){ 
        echo "['".$row['kode_sales']."','".$row['provinsi']."',".$row['gaji'].",".$row['T_nasabah']."],";
        }

        //console.log(dataFromPHP);
        console.log((data));

        tree = new google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        tree.draw(data, {
          minColor: '#f00',
          midColor: '#ddd',
          maxColor: '#0d0',
          headerHeight: 15,
          fontColor: 'black',
          showScale: true

        });
        chart.draw(data, options);  
        }
        })
```

And always to getting "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" on this line (btw I got this line after I run php file and from Google Chrome > Right click > Inspect Element > Console)

```
function drawChart(){
        //var dataFromPHP = [
{
    "kode_client": "CLI01", <<<------- SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
    "nama": "Edo",
    "tanggal_lahir": "01\/05\/1967",
    "alamat": "Nusa Hijau",
    "telp": "085634234",
    "produk": "Titanium",
    "gaji": "5000000",
    "cabang": "Bandung",
    "provinsi": "Jawa Barat",
    "kode_sales": "CLI02"
},
{
    "kode_client": "CLI02",
    "nama": "Santoso Imam",
    "tanggal_lahir": "15\/12\/1979",
    "alamat": "Padasuka",
    "telp": "08513087645",
    "produk": "Investra Link",
    "gaji": "4500000",
    "cabang": "Cimahi",
    "provinsi": "Jawa Tengah",
    "kode_sales": "SAL04"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you copied the entire file?

Comment: hmm I think I already copied all of entire file @MaxMeijer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is recommended to use the following library when loading *google charts*...

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

and if using `loader.js`, **the load statement is incorrect...**

`google.charts.load('visualization', {packages:['treemap']}); //<-- wrong`

should be...

`google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['treemap']});`

the first argument should be the version to load

when using the older `jsapi` library,
the load statement would look something like this...

`google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['treemap']});`

but according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently.

**EDIT**

this line is incorrect...

`echo "['".$row['provinsi']."','".$row['lala']."',"0,0"],";`

change to...

`echo "['".$row['provinsi']."','".$row['lala']."',0,0],";`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I still confuse about loader.js. If it is incorrect, so what should I use to replace loader.js? Or just delete it?

Comment: this is my new source code after update in and still getting error "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement". Here my source code. http://pastebin.com/wDy7UVf3 and whats wrong with my code? Treemap chart did't showing on browser

Comment: using `loader.js` is correct but the `load` statement should be --> `google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['treemap']});` -- can't get to _pastebin_ from current location -- edit question with updated code instead...

Comment: still on the same error and same line. @WhiteHat :( and why JSON file into error and as far as I know JSON format is correct.

Comment: i'm confused, is the json hard-coded as in the question, within `drawChart`? if so, why is this commented out? `//var dataFromPHP = [` <-- that will cause an error -- and it looks like you're assigning `$json` from `file_get_contents` but it is never used.

Comment: no no, I take json from this code '`$dataFromPHP = file_get_contents('clientdata.json');` but if I run json file always appear like in the question

Comment: ahh you're right @WhiteHat, I comment `var dataFromPHP = <?php echo file_get_contents('clientdata.json'); ?>;` and "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" is gone

Comment: I.m getting error "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" from this line `$provinsi = 'SELECT provinsi , LEFT(provinsi, '') AS lala FROM data_client';`

Comment: need to escape inner quotes or use double quotes, i.e. change to --> `'SELECT provinsi , LEFT(provinsi, \'\') AS lala FROM data_client';` -- or -- `'SELECT provinsi , LEFT(provinsi, "") AS lala FROM data_client';`

Comment: ahh my bad, i write `LEFT(provinsi, ' ')` how about `echo "['".$row['lala']."', null, 0, 0],";`?  where I missing ";" before statement ? ._.